# using copy %0 >file.bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

I tried using the command in the title in the way below. (lets call the file with that command in it file.bat)
`copy copy %0 address >file1.bat`
when in went into file1.bat it has  `copy "address of file.bat" address`.
How do I make it put %0 in file1.bat as plain text?
sorry, I am inexperienced at batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters with special significance to batch require a preceding "escape" character to suspend their special meaning (just for that one instance).

The escape for **most** characters is `^`, so to output a literal `>` you'd need `^>`.

The escape for `%` however is `%`, so for a literal `%0` you'd need `%%0` in an echo`.